# Can Joda format dates for Arabic locale using Arabic digits?

Tags: java, internationalization, jodatime, icu

The story so far...

We got sick of Java's Date API being generally bad and eventually ended up adopting Joda Time, which works much more sanely (although it is not perfect.)

Recently we have been noticing issues in Java's NumberFormat with respect to Arabic locale. Essentially, it uses the "latin" digits instead of the more natural "arab" digits. So I have been adopting ICU's formatters as drop-in replacements for Java's.

Now I have noticed that Joda's formatters for dates print the numbers in Latin as well. For example, if you take the following program:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.ibm.icu.text.DateFormat;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestJoda {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Locale locale = new Locale("ar", "SA");

        DateFormat icuDateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
            DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);
        System.out.println("ICU: " + icuDateFormat.format(new Date()));

        DateTimeFormatter jodaDateTimeFormatter =
            DateTimeFormat.longDateTime().withLocale(locale);
        System.out.println("Joda: " + jodaDateTimeFormatter.print(DateTime.now()));
    }
}
```

The output will be as follows:

```
ICU: ٤ أغسطس، ٢٠١٤ ٥:٠٧:١٤ م جرينتش+١٠
Joda: 04 أغسطس, 2014 EST 05:07:14 م
```

Is there some way to coerce Joda's formatters into outputting a style consistent to ICU's?

I guess in the worst case there would be a way to implement some kind of adapter, but one of the nice things about Joda's classes is their immutability, a feature which ICU has unfortunately been slow to adopt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joda only supports ASCII digits, it's hardcoded.

You can always use `String.replace`, and/or wrap `DateTimeFormatter` into a proxy.

Comment: Disappointing, but still better to know than not to know. Wrapping it in an implementation which corrects the digits seems practical enough (but I'd have to watch out for any new code people might write which gets a formatter without wrapping it. And that EST translates to something as well...)

Comment: Actually it looks like neither solution is really practical in the full context. String.replace fixes the digits but not other things the JRE format doesn't format natively, such as the time zone. And DateTimeFormatter... well, that should be technically possible, but it's a very difficult-looking formatter interface to implement.

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

I tried using the built-in automatic localization feature of the [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. Looks like this behaves the same as Joda-Time, using [Westernized digits rather than Eastern Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals).

Capture the current moment in UTC. Adjust into a time zone.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now ();
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone ( ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

Generate a String to represent the date-time value.

```
Locale l = new Locale ( "ar" , "MA" ); // Arabic language, cultural norms of Morocco.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime ( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale ( l );
```

Dump to console.

```
String output = zdt.format ( f );
System.out.println ( "zdt.toString(): " + zdt );
System.out.println ( "output: " + output );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2017-01-01T15:06:34.255-05:00[America/Montreal]
>
> output: 01 يناير, 2017 EST 03:06:34 م

I am not sure if Arabic will copy-paste correctly here. See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/9OSWM6).

Conclusion: **By default, java.time uses Westernized digits** for Arabic.

There may be a way to override this behavior with [java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html), but I do not know.